# Connection to localhost refused in Ubuntu subsystem on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have made a server-client model in python on Linux. When I run the server on Ubuntu Subsystem on Windows, it works just fine. But when I run the client(which tries to connect to the server) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "client.py", line 64, in <module>
s.connect('127.0.0.1',port)
File "client.py", line 19, in connect
self.sock.connect((host, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The server is listening on localhost and port = 14345 and client is trying to connect to the same. I also tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 14345` and it gave me same error:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I also tried `netstat -an` in cmd on Windows and it showed this

```
TCP    127.0.1.1:14345        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

This means the server is indeed listening, but the client from Linux subsystem is not able to connect to it.

Also the code is working fine on real Linux (I mean Ubuntu installed on hard disk).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using third-party antivirus/firewalls in Windows, try temporarily deactivating them and see if the connection goes back to normal. As a security measure you can temporarily use the built-in Windows antivirus/firewall programs instead. If you are using Ubuntu in WSL you can install the gufw application to manage your Linux firewall.

It's a known issue that third-party firewalls do not behave well with Windows Subsystem for Linux. See [No internet with 3rd party AV/Firewall](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/475) and [apt-get update and install failing](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1720) for details.